# StatusCode: BadRequest - When calling RestAPI using RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, restful-url

I am calling a RestAPI and sending data in json format. Using RestSharp as client.

Have following function. Please have a look over it.

```
public HttpStatusCode  CreatOrder(OrderRequest order,string token)
{
    var client = new RestClient("this is url of api");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order); //using Json.Net 
    request.AddJsonBody(order);
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return response.StatusCode;
}
```

I can see following json during debugging.

```
"{\"waypoints\":[{\"exactLatLng\":[{\"lat\":123.0,\"lng\":234.0}],\"premise\":null,\"houseNumber\":null,\"street\":null,\"subLocality\":null,\"locality\":null,\"city\":null,\"district\":null,\"province\":null,\"country\":null,\"postalCode\":null,\"countryCode\":null,\"poiName\":null,\"placeLatLng\":[{\"lat\":123.0,\"lng\":234.0}]}],\"extraOptions\":null,\"client\":{\"clientId\":null,\"name\":\"NumanTest\",\"phone\":\"1213123\",\"imageUrl\":null},\"name\":\"NumanTest\",\"notes\":null,\"unitOfLength\":[],\"tripDistance\":null,\"tripDuration\":null,\"pickupTime\":null,\"numberOfSeats\":null,\"vehicleType\":[],\"tariffType\":[],\"paymentMethods\":[],\"prepaid\":null,\"tariffId\":null}"
```

But i always get Bad Request in Response.

```
"StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 2325)"
```

Can you please help me get rid of this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to add the `Content-Type`-header to the request, too:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Additionally you could use a web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler.net) to take a look at the actual http request that's being sent to the service.

Comment: Thanks man.
But after adding content type, i am getting same result

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the right content? Is your `order`-object serialized correctly?